# Hover entire TR if tr has class

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have two classes that I am assigning to TR's as they are building built into my datatables.  However I cannot get hover to function in a way that the whole TR is highlighted when I hover a TD.

The attached jsfiddle has it only hovering the td's which is where I am currently stuck.

```
.accessible :hover{
    background-color: rgb(206,246,206);
}
.inAccessible :hover{
    background-color: rgb(255,87,87);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Y3JDd/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

get rid of the space between the class and the `:hover` :

```
.accessible:hover{
    background-color: rgb(206,246,206);
}
.inAccessible:hover{
    background-color: rgb(255,87,87);
}
```